# Imagemagick segmentation-fault

Tags: imagemagick, segmentation-fault

I [statically compiled Imagemagick](https://travis-ci.org/kvz/imagemagick-static-builder). Converting images works well so far. But when I run `identify -list delegate` it shows my delegates, but then exits with "Aborted (core dumped)".

Here is the `strace -f` https://gist.github.com/kvz/9385813

What could I have done wrong?

Comment: more interesting that an `strace` would be a [`backtrace`](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToGetABacktrace)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I added a backtrace here now https://gist.github.com/kvz/9385813/#comment-1185658. It mentions `gvFreeContext`, so possibly a graphviz issue..?

Comment: @kvz That isn't really a backtrace, it's just the frame it crashed on. You need to run the `bt` command after it segfaults to get the backtrace

Comment: Last version? Any strange configuration? Up to date dependencies? Have you checked upstream if this is perhaps a known bug?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @umläute's comment I used `gdb` for enhanced debugging. 
Here's how I backtraced `./target/bin/identify -list delegate`:

```
$ gdb ./target/bin/identify
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /usr/src/imagemagick-static/target/bin/identify...done.
(gdb) run -list delegate
```

This generated much more useful output than strace did:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000072eaa5 in gvFreeContext ()
```

Googling for `gvFreeContext` allowed me to narrow down further debugging on Graphviz.

Michael Mrozek suggested to then type

```
(gdb) bt
```

That gives the full backtrace:

```
#0  0x000000000094ce21 in gvFreeContext ()
#1  0x000000000049fe4f in UnregisterDOTImage ()
#2  0x0000000000452e5c in UnregisterStaticModules ()
#3  0x0000000000423013 in MagickCoreTerminus ()
#4  0x000000000040cc38 in IdentifyMain ()
#5  0x000000000040cc64 in main ()
```

I haven't solved my segfault just yet, but `gdb` [backtraces](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToGetABacktrace) seem the way to debug them when nor stderr nor `dmesg` nor `kern.log` contain good clues.

Comment: If you're going to debug it, you need to build with debug symbols (`-g`) or not strip them out (make sure `install` doesn't have the `-s` option). The GDB would actually give a backtrace, to the particular line of code...